# Linux disk imaging and booting

Tags: linux, boot, clonezilla

I have a Centos 7 system - boot, home, and root are all on seperate partitions on a single 500GB disk - which the system boots from.

What i want to do is to use an imaging program once a month to take an EXACT BOOTABLE image of the system - very little changes on those partitions from month to month - but rebuilding would be a giant pain.

I am happy to shut the system down once a month to complete this task and to boot from a live CD.

If i equate this to the Windows world i would image the system to another drive and then be able at any time to replace the existing drive with the imaged drive and have a high confidence level that the system would boot OK.

It does not seem to be the case in Linux, i have tried a number of different systems, CLonezilla, Ghost for Linux, commandline DD and numerous others - whilst all of them complete the job, not one has been able to deliver me the end result of having the system boot up from the new drive. Each of them dump me into the GRUB rescue system and then force me to go looking for various files to edit.

It appears that none of the imaging apps that i have used are able to write identical UUIDs to the disks and this is where GRUB falls over. (Correct me if i am wrong here)

Based on the research that i have done using google - Linux people just seem to accept this as how it is and do not see it as an issue.

Have i interpreted this correctly - or is there a magic tool that will deliver me an imaged system that i can boot and operate from simply by replacing a hard drive ?

Happy to take any advice or be pointed to software (commercial or otherwise) that will do this.

Sorry as requested the system is working with a "traditional" non UEFI BIOS i.e. MBR style.

Craig

Comment: OK i have achieved this now. I could not get the Clonezilla disks to work (pulled from the Clonezilla site) - but instead purchased a copy of PartedMagic from 2019. This used Clonezilla but performed additional magic at the end to make the newly cloned drives able to be booted.